# The region bounded by $y^2=4ax$, the $x$-axis, and the line $x=a$ is rotated about $x=-a$. Find the volume of the solid.

Tags: definite-integrals

> The plane figure bounded by the parabola $y^2=4ax$, the x-axis and the ordinate at $x=a$, is rotated a complete revolution about the line $x=-a$. Find the volume of the solid generated.

I tried to integrate this by putting a and - a as the upper and lower limits but to no avail
$$\pi\int_{a}^{a} 4ax\mathrm{dx}$$

How do I go about answering this question?

> Then, what does it mean to rotate a curve about a line?

Comment: It's always useful to draw a picture. Here's an interactive figure: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/crhn7fcz2e
When you imagine what the rotated volume looks like, it turns out the be kind of a donut, with a flat outer wall. The centre of the donut is at $x=-a$ and the flat outer wall is at $x=a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express $y$ as a function of $x$ for the first quadrant: $y=2\sqrt{ax}$. Use the restriction that $a>0$ (for negative values of $a$, you would get the same volume because the solid is symmetric with respect to the axis of revolution) and shift the curve along the $x$-axis $a$ units to the right: $y=2\sqrt{a(x-a)}$. And then you're going to use shell integration with the bounds of $a$ and $2a$:

$$
V=2\pi\int_{a}^{2a}x\cdot 2\sqrt{a(x-a)}\,dx=4\pi\int_{a}^{2a}x\sqrt{ax-a^2}\,dx.
$$

You can use the substitution $u=ax-a^2$ to solve that integral:

$$
\frac{4\pi}{a^2}\int_{a}^{2a}(ax-a^2+a^2)\sqrt{ax-a^2}\frac{d}{dx}(ax-a^2)\,dx=\\
\frac{4\pi}{a^2}\int_{0}^{a^2}(u+a^2)\sqrt{u}\,du=
\frac{4\pi}{a^2}\int_{0}^{a^2}(u^{\frac{3}{2}}+a^2u^{\frac{1}{2}})\,du.
$$

From this point on, the integration is trivial.